# Search database for close points

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do i plug javascript variables into a database query?
Variables for: current location, latitude, longitude, distance, number of results to display.
I got the SELECT from the second tutorial.

```
$sth = $db->query("SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM dealers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;");
```

Here are my variables

This is my goal:
I would like to build a poi locating map that provides a list of a number of nearest poi (based on user declared var), and gets directions to desired poi from their current geolocation or one that they entered. Basically, google maps with were the points are read from a selected database. 
If you have any recourse suggestions, I'd be glad to have them.
Here's what I've sited so far:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

http://www.domagojsalopek.com/Details/Display-locations-from-a-database-on-a-map-using-Google-Maps-JavaScript-API-and-PHP/22

Comment: maybe i should learn ajax?

Comment: Yes. if you're doing the queries on the server, you'll need a way to send your JS data over to the server, and AJAX is the current standard way to do that.